# WiFi on MacBook Pro (12,1 - Early 2015)

Tags: wifi, networking, drivers, macbook

After following instructions in a number of other threads, I am still unable to get the built-in WiFi on my 13" MacBook Pro (12,1) to show up or work under the latest version of elementaryOS. Thankfully, my Thunderbolt to Ethernet adapter works flawlessly.

Naturally, we're dealing with a Broadcom chip, which from my research are some of the most difficult to get working under Linux.

Running **sudo lshw -C network** gives me the following output:

```
  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=wl latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:c1400000-c1407fff memory:c1000000-c13fffff
```

Running **lspci -nn -d 14e4:** gives me the following output:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)
```

My specific chip, Broadcom BCM34602 [43ba, rev 1] says it is supported by [brcmsmac 3.17+](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/brcm80211), but I am too much of a Linux newbie to know how to install this to test it.

Any thoughts for how to proceed? Thanks so much for your assistance. :)

Answer (score 4):

This came up on ask Ubuntu and I see one of the comments says the answer worked on Loki. [Check Here for full details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622988/wifi-issues-with-macbook-pro-retina-early-2015-12-2-on-ubuntu-15-04/624746#624746)

Here's what it says to do.

Download this [firmware](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin)

In the terminal:

cd /lib/firmware/brcm

(If folder doesn't exist then...)

sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/brcm

cd ~/Downloads

sudo mv brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin

sudo reboot

Or reboot however you normally do it. I do see a note on ask ubuntu saying "You might have to run apt-get update and apt-get upgrade." I'd reboot and see if it works without doing that first.

Comment: On my MBP (11,2) there is BRCM4360, but it fails to work with loaded `b43`-module. I got the Wi-Fi working by following https://askubuntu.com/a/1312109/781971. It suggest installing a "tainted" driver for `wl` with command `apt install broadcom-sta-dkms`. It will build a non-GPL -driver from sources, but makes laptop usable.