# Wifi Option not showing up + Boot Method

Tags: wifi, macbook, elementary-website, efi

Hoping to get help with two quick questions. I'm moving from MacOS to Elementary so fairly new to the Linux world

1. I flashed ElementaryOS based on installation instructions and then booted my Macbook. I see EFI Boot for 2 out of 3 options. Is doing EFI boot okay and safe to do? I was able to start the installation guide from EFI, but wanted to know if any risks came with this
2. I played around in live mode before going ahead and doing full install of Elementary and I couldn't get wifi to work. I only saw three options: 1) Wired 2)VPN 3)Proxy.

I saw another post where the OP outlined that these instructions worked: [No wifi on Macbook Pro mid 2010](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16102/no-wifi-on-macbook-pro-mid-2010/24789#24789). Will be trying this out, but curious to know if this could be something else.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I have a 2013 Macbook Air and cannot get the WiFi enabled. I had this working on Hera 5.1. I tried the commands above and rebooted; no joy yet. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I just today installed eOS 6 (beta 2) on a mid-2010 MacBook Pro, specifically model MacBookPro 7,1. To get the wifi options to show up, I followed these steps:

1. Remove the bcmwl-kernel-source package (if you installed it), then reboot:

```
    sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
    reboot
```

2. Install the b43 broadcom firmware:

```
    sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

3. Reload the package

```
    sudo modprobe -r b43
    sudo modprobe b43
```

You should now see the wifi options appear. Source: [Elementary OS on Macbook won't display wifi settings. How do i fix?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11783/elementary-os-on-macbook-wont-display-wifi-settings-how-do-i-fix)

And I also selected the EFI boot, that should be a fine way to go.